# Lining Up Radio Items With CSS

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2

I'm pretty new to CSS and not much of a designer, but I'm trying to add it to some JSF radio select items that I made, but I can't quite get what I need.

I'm trying to get them to show up pretty evenly under each of the items, all three of which pretty much look like this:

```
<h:selectOneRadio type="reset" id="SelectNativity" value="#{searchBean.nativity}" rendered="#{searchBean.byNativity}" styleClass="searchByOtherRadio">
<f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Native"><br/></f:selectItem>
<f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="Nonnative"></f:selectItem>
<f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="Both Native and Nonnative in parts of its US range"></f:selectItem>
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

and the CSS looks like this:

```
.searchByOtherRadio{
    font-family: Verdana; 
    font-size: small; 
    color: #000;
    padding-left:20px;
    width: 75%;}
```

Basically, how can I get the second two items under nativity to move close to the first and how can I get the second items in invasiveness and federal legal status to line up under the second item in nativity, using css?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `layout` attribute on `h:selectOneRadio` as `pageDirection`, No need for CSS.

There are 2 possible values for `layout`:

- `lineDirection` - For Horizontal Direction
- `pageDirection` - For Vertical direction.

Default value is `lineDirection`.

```
<h:selectOneRadio layout="pageDirection"  type="reset" id="SelectNativity"  styleClass="searchByOtherRadio">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Native"></f:selectItem>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="Nonnative"></f:selectItem>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="Both Native and Nonnative in parts of its US range"></f:selectItem>
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to do this by adding:

`display: block;` to the CSS I posted.

And several `&nbsp;` after the text on `ItemLabel="XYZ"`